# Is it possible to allocate different memory location for structure members in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, pragma

For the following structure object

```
struct test
{ 
int a;       //expect address location 0xabcd
int b;       //expect address location 0xmnop
} test1;
```

The expectation is to have different memory locations assigned for variable a and variable b for test1 instance.

I understand that such a thing is possible for global variables by using 
 #pragma address

**Questions 1:** Can this also be extended to structures too.

if Not then,

**Question 2:** What is a better way to do this?

**The constraints are:**

1. Both variables must stay together logically.
2. The physical addresses must be separate(configurable somehow).

**Edit 1:**
To clarify further, The above structure contains variables that indicate the locations in a certain buffer. (closest analogy will be the Read/Write indexes in a queue) 
Here, however, each variable must be stored in a separate location to be protected from accidental access by some modules.

Comment: *Why?* What is the *real* problem you try to solve? This question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why ? is it even needed ? What is the actual problem that you have ?

Comment: `struct test { int *a; int *b; } test1 = { 0xabcd, 0xmnop, }`

Comment: Maybe pointers are what you are looking for, but I do not really see what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Lundin I understand the answer given there, but I do not get the connection. I just wanted to say that something like this might be possible to accomplish with pointers (like in your answer). Not that adding a `*` is the solution

Comment: What do you mean by "accidental access by some modules"? Do you have a multi-threaded application with multiple threads sharing this data? What is a "module"?

Comment: Clarifications and additions to the question should be edited into the question and not written in a comment. This helps to understand the question by just reading the question, without having to dig through the comments.

Comment: And I should probably have posted this earlier, but please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your comments. This was my first post. 
I will read thoroughly the guidelines and respect your suggestions from the next occasion onwards.

Comment: Why not just use two variables? `int test1_a; int test1_b;`

Answer (score 4):

Per definition<sup>1)</sup>, a `struct`'s members are allocated after each other in memory. In addition, allocating different struct members in different memory areas does not make any sense what-so-ever. Not even on the most exotic embedded systems.

Question 1: No, you cannot and should not do this. Neither with the standard C language, nor with compiler extensions like #pragmas.

Question 2: Use pointers.

```
typedef struct
{ 
  volatile uint32_t* a;
  volatile uint32_t* b;
} test_t;

test_t test = 
{ 
  .a = (volatile uint32_t*)0x1234;
  .b = (volatile uint32_t*)0x5678;
};
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> From C17 6.7.2.1 §6

> ...a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose
>   storage is allocated in an ordered sequence, ...

Comment: That is what I was thinking about. Whether or not that helps OP is for him to decide.